# I'm trying to add values of 2 properties in a function but value of 1 property is giving undefined. I just need the increase in % of css bar

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to increase the percent of bar in terms of rate(input given by the user). Once the user submits his input, the value should be increased by that input. How do i achieve this using ng-style.

```
  var tech = [
    {name: "android", rate: 0, bar: 10},
    {name: "angular", rate: 0, bar: 10},
    {name: "node", rate: 0, bar: 10},
    {name: "maven", rate: 0, bar: 10},
    {name: "log", rate:0, bar: 10},
    {name: "vs2019", rate: 0, bar: 10}
  ];

  $scope.tech = tech;

  $scope.incrementRate= function(t,r)
  {
     t.rate = r;
     t.bar = parseInt(t.bar) + Number(r); //giving NaN
     alert(t.bar); //giving undefined
  };
```

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select course:</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control contact-text" name="course" ng-model="tech.name">
        <option ng-repeat="t in tech" ng-value="t.name">{{t.name}}</option>
      </select> 
      <br> 
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Rate:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="ml-3" name="rate" value="1" checked ng-model="tech.rate"> 1
      <input type="radio" class="ml-3" name="rate" value="2" ng-model="tech.rate"> 2
      <input type="radio" class="ml-3" name="rate" value="3" ng-model="tech.rate"> 3
      <input type="radio" class="ml-3" name="rate" value="4" ng-model="tech.rate"> 4
      <input type="radio" class="ml-3" name="rate" value="5" ng-model="tech.rate"> 5
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" 
       name="rate" class="btn btn-primary" 
       ng-click="incrementRate(tech,tech.rate)">Rate</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- for eg, -->

Android:
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="android skills" ng-style="{'width':tech[0].bar+'%'}">
        {{tech[0].bar+'%'}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `r = t.rate;` instead of `t.rate=r; `

Answer (score 1):

`t.bar` is `undefined` because in the place you're calling `incrementRate(tech,tech.rate)`, the `tech` is `$scope.tech` - the list of all technologies. Not the `t` you're using in `ng-repeat`.

Basically you're mixing `tech` as the list of techs and tech as the selected technology. I suggest you use `$scope.techList` as the list and `$scope.tech` as the selected technology.

Use `ng-model="tech"` and [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for the `select` to be able to select tech.

Comment: If i use `$scope.tech= $scope.techList[0];` then after submitting i get undefined for all the properties .i have used `ng-model="tech" and passing tech as a parameter to the function . still no luck

Comment: Where do you get undefined?

Comment: inside the function `alert(tech.name +' '+tech.bar)`

Comment: There is no such function in your code. Use `t` instead of `tech`

Answer (score 0):

You define `$scope.tech` as an array:

```
$scope.tech = [
 {...}
];
```

But in your view you are trying to access it as if it were an object with a `rate` property that does not exist:

```
<button type="submit" 
  ng-click="incrementRate(tech,tech.rate)">Rate</button>
<!-- tech is an array, and has no property called `rate`-->
```

If you place some log messages here, you will see the error:

```
  $scope.incrementRate= function(t,r)
  {
     console.log(t) // Array(6)
     console.log(r) // Undefined!
     ...

  };
```

Further, it's a poor choice to assign the model for your `select` component as a property of an array. That is very confusing. Use a dedicated variable to assign the selected item. You have also made things very difficult for yourself by using `ngRepeat` with options instead of `ngOptions`. With this approach you only have access to a string representation of the item and not the item object itself.

```
<select ng-model="selectedTech" ng-options="t as t.name for t in tech track by t.name">
</select>
```

Now you can reference the selected item in your function:

```
<button type="submit" 
  ng-click="incrementRate(selectedTech)">Rate</button>
```

```
$scope.incrementRate= function(techItem)
{
  console.log(techItem) // {name: "angular", rate: 0, bar: 10},
  console.log(techItem.rate) // 0
  ...

};
```

Since the `selectedTech` is a property of `$scope` you don't really even need to pass it in as a variable:

```
<button type="submit" 
  ng-click="incrementRate()">Rate</button>
```

```
$scope.incrementRate= function()
{
  console.log($scope.selectedTech) // {name: "angular", rate: 0, bar: 10},
  console.log($scope.selectedTech.rate) // 0
  ...

};
```